# Why was my edit rejected but the same edit made by the author?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2785516) which the post's author rejected. The author then made the same edit to the post. Is this acceptable behavior?

Comment: **[FIDDLE DEMO]** is not the same thing as [Fiddle Demo].

Comment: @Mat caps small is a problem?

Comment: Caps is not a small problem. It's A VERY LARGE PROBLEM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition the behavior is acceptable because the system allows it and there are no mechanisms in place to combat it. It's also a very small problem: there are thousands of posts that need edits. Even if this one author behaved in an anti-community manner, you shouldn't let it get you down. Instead, move on and edit posts of people who are more grateful.

Comment: I agree with your answer. I would also, personally add in this specific case that the author's edit is not exactly the same, though, and is better than the proposed edit.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Ok I accept you people.... he is only did the correct edit I like to know the capital letter will give the attentions to the text so that I gave in capital is it worst?...

Comment: @Thiru You should pretty much never do capital letters like that, no. Except when you are typing in code that uses all capital letters.

Comment: @AndrewBarber ok thanks for advice, I will keep it in mind... here I came to clarify my doubt you and Nanthaniel Ford are cleared my doubt, but I couldn't understand why here I am getting minus to my question meta is to ask the user specific doubts and support too is it?

Comment: @Thirumalai What gets downvoted in meta tends to be a different set of things than what is downvoted in other S.E. sites. In particular, questions that are focused on one's personal experience ("Why did I get dinged for this?" "Why doesn't the system let me do that?") tend to be downvoted; they've been asked many times before and tend to not get to the broader questions that improve the platform. Thus, people downvote them as not interesting. Best not to take your meta rep seriously at all.

Comment: @NathanielFord I am not thinking serious of meta reputation but If I am getting much down vote I will not be able to post the question further is it? and even though it asked many time its particular to some user (ex: I am asking why my post get downvote is different by other users Why I get the down vote-  Each will have different answer am I correct?)

Comment: @Thirumalai They're not significantly different questions, though: you can interpolate from all those others why you had a problem. But the thing people really downvote are questions that are self-focused. "Why me?" is never a popular question; it can come off as whining or self-involved, and not as an attempt to better the community. Questions that fall into the latter category are well-researched and ask a question obviously applicable to many people. I'm not saying you're whining; I'm just saying that people tend to downvote questions that aren't broadly applicable.